# function $g: Q\times Q \to Q\times Q$ such that $g(x,y) = (2x + 3y, 3x + 2y)$ if $ x,y\in Q$, need to prove that g is reversible function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know that a reversible function is a function that is onto and injective, how can I prove that?

Comment: How about finding its inverse?

Answer (score 1):

Solve $$ 2x+3y=a, 3x+2y=b$$ for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a$ and $b$

You get $$ x=\frac {3b-2a}{5}, y=\frac {3a-2b}{5}$$

Thus for every pair $(a,b)$ of rational numbers you have $$g(\frac {3b-2a}{5},\frac {3a-2b}{5})=(a,b)$$

Thus we have $$g^{-1} (a,b) = (\frac {3b-2a}{5},\frac {3a-2b}{5})$$

That is the function $g$ is reversible.

Comment: Does this solution show that g is onto and injective? because I need to prove she's reversible and only then find g^-1

Comment: Yes, this is a proof for one-to one and onto property of $g$ by showing the unique pre- image for every (a,b).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

This function is linear so just check if $G$ takes only zero vector to zero vector, i.e. $\ker (G)=\{0\}$